# C++: Can I write a template class that derives from T?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, radix, derived

I'm not exactly sure how to word this in English, but I want to do something like this:

```
template <class T>
class derived: public T
{ blah };
```

Where basically, I have a template class, but I'm deriving a new class from the class that is specified in the template? I.e. so I wouldn't necessarily know the class at compile time.

Is this even possible? 
If so, What are the semantics for this?

For example, say I'm trying to write a "parent" class. For the purposes of this example, let's say it's a tree parent. The tree parent, is a tree itself (so it inherits from tree), but also has a vector of references to child trees.
However, the parent class itself doesn't have to be a tree; it could be any class, such that I could write something like:

```
Parent<tree> treeParent;
Parent<shrub> shrubParent;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should just try it before posting?

Comment: I was at a computer that didn't have a compiler, or at least, I didn't have a lot of time to try and find one on it. Nawaz kindly pointed me to an online IDE.

Comment: You can even take it one step further, and define a class `Derived : Base<Derived>`, so the class inherits from a base class which knows about the derived class :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That is possible. Try doing that.

> I wouldn't necessarily know the class at compile time.

I think, you mean *"I wouldn't necessarily know the class at the time of **defining the class template**."*

By the time you compile, you've already defined the class template, and used it in your code, passing template argument to it, which means you know the class (i.e  template argument) at compile time. If you don't know the class to be used as `base`, then you cannot even compile the code.

Comment: Thanks! 
I'm taking a moment between classes to ask this question on a school computer, so I didn't have a chance to compile what I was thinking.

Comment: @TragicPixel: Try compiling. You can also use `www.ideone.com`. It is an online compiler.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed possible and commonly used for [policy based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design):

Like in this incredibly contrived example:

```
template<typename OutputPolicy>
struct Writer : public OutputPolicy {
  using OutputPolicy::print;
  void write(const std::string&) {
    //do some formatting etc.
    print(string);
  }
};

class StdoutPolicy {
public:
  set_linebreaks(const std::string&);
protected:
  void print(const std::string&);
};
```

The public method in the policy will be accessible through `Writer`. That way a policy can decorate the class it is used in with additional methods.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it is a kind of policy based design.

Comment: @Nawaz If you have a comprehensive real-world example at hand please add it to the answer. Otherwise I try to look for on later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. The semantic for this is no different from the semantic for any other use of a template parameter in the class template. You can have a member of type T, a function parameter of type T, and you can have T as a base class too. It's not special.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>class classTemplateBase
{
    public:
       T value;
       classTemplateBase(T i)
       {
          this->value = i;
       }
       void test()
       {
          cout << value << endl;
       }
};

class classTemplateChild : public classTemplateBase<char>
{
    public:
       classTemplateChild( ): classTemplateBase<char>( 0 )  // default char is NUL
       {
          ;
       }

       classTemplateChild(char c): classTemplateBase<char>( c )
       {
          ;
       }
       void test2()
       {
          test();
       }
};

int main()
 {
      classTemplateBase <int> a( 42 );
      classTemplateChild b( 'A' );

      a.test();   // should print "42"
      b.test();   // should print "A"
      b.test2();  // should print "A"

  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible an it is also very common and has gotten it's own name: the Curiously recurring template pattern. See the [Wikipeida entry on Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).